# Computing Units affect GPU only or high RAM also?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I recently bought Google Colab Pro, which gives me access to better GPU & higher RAM but limited with 100 computing units.

I want to confirm something. If I run out of computing units, am I only unable to use the better GPUs or will I also be unable to use the high RAM?